# Uganda Child travelling to the UK

Tags: uganda

What type of visa does a child travelling alone to the UK from Uganda need and how much is the visa.

Comment: Reason for travel? Age of child? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just for a visit they will need a standard visitor visa, which i'm guessing as you are on a travel site. The link below has information for a child travelling along

> You can travel to the UK without an adult (someone over the age of
>   18).
>
> Your parent or guardian will need to provide their:
>
> - written consent for you to travel to the UK
> - full contact details
>
> They’ll also need to provide proof that you have somewhere suitable to
>   live during your stay in the UK, including:
>
> - the name and date of birth of the person that you will be staying    with an address where you will be living
> - details of your relationship to the person who’ll be looking after    you
> - consent in writing so they can look after you during your stay in the    UK

[link for standard visitor visa for U18](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18)

> A Standard Visitor visa costs £89
>
> - 2 years - £337
> - 5 years - £612
> - 10 years - £767

[link for costs](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa)

If you are applying for a visa for the child to move to the UK you will need a family visa

[link for family visas](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/child)